# How to allow users with the member role to upload images as public in an Openstack Cloud?

Tags: openstack, roles

I've tried changing the /etc/glance/policy.json and setting the following:

```
"publicize_image": "role:member",
```

And then restarting both the glance-api and glance-registry services but of course that would be too easy so it doesn't work :)

```
openstack image create --file gammy_image.iso JACOBS-GAMMY-IMAGE --public
403 Forbidden
You are not authorized to complete publicize_image action.
    (HTTP 403)
```

Comment: What is the exact error you get (if any)?

Comment: No error when editing the config files or restarting the services. I've updated the question with the error I get when I try to upload an image as public.

Answer (score 0):

I often upload image with command:

```
glance image-create --name "cirros" --file ./cirros.qcow2 --disk-format qcow2 --container-format bare --visibility public --progress
```

And it works fine, all users can see my image.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- add the admin role to your user;

```
openstack role add --user USER_NAME --project PROJECT_NAME admin
```

- remove the need for admin rights for this operation

As an administrator, edit the file /etc/glance/policy.json and change the following line:

"publicize_image": "role:admin",
With:

"publicize_image": "",
Then restart glance:

```
$ sudo glance-control all restart
```